# Foundation 5 clearing lightbox not working with angularjs dynamic images

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to use the clearing lightbox component from Zurb Foundation 5 into my angularjs application but I haven't found the way, example code here:

Using the code below what I get is a mess but it should look like the [Foundation Clearing documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>       
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ClearingController">
        <ul class="clearing-thumbs large-12 columns small-block-grid-4" data-clearing>
            <li ng-repeat="imagen in imagenes"><a href="{{imagen}}"><img ng-src="{{imagen}}"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                angular.module('app', [])
                        .controller('ClearingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                                $scope.imagenes = ["http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image1", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image2", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image3", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image4", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image5", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image6", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image7", "http://placehold.it/1000x1000&text=image8"];
                                $(document).foundation();
                            }]);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do anyone have an idea about how to make it work?

Comment: Can you please explain what is not working here?

Comment: The clearing-thumbs doesn't work, it look like a mess inside the angularjs application. If you copy the example code in a plunker or any html file you will see how it looks but it should look like in the [Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/clearing.html).

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/5vTUBcOLikQYEZNbcz2M?p=preview The border is not visible or any other bug that I can't see?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant when you click an image everything becomes a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while testing it threw `Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined`
so added http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js, internally used by foundation.js

as per the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html) `$(document).foundation();` should be before `</body>` and `$(document).foundation();` initialize Foundation scripts so moved out of the angular scope.

example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNwGQq

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my 2 cents here, as bootstrapping Modernizr can be heavy, and especially extraneous if you're only using it to get rid of a few event errors propogated by Foundation element click events.

But! There's a work around. Just extending an empty Modernizr prototype clears the Foundation errors for me, and the Foundation click event behaviour is working correctly.

`let Modernizr = {};`